# Simulating control characters such as "H key" , "UP arrow key" , etc

Tags: linux, fifo, control-characters

I have a Device 1 which has debian OS installed on it. I access the serial console of it through other device i.e. Device 2 . I have scripts on the device 2 which will uninstall and install different OS on the device 1 . The device 1 while doing the installation/uninstallation asks for key presses like "v" , "up arraow key" etc . I have automated the whole task by giving the input to the program through a fifo (file input file output) file. After a lot of reasearch i found out a way to simulate up arrow key through the below command

```
printf "\u001b[A" > input.fifo
```

When it is written to the .fifo file the device 1 takes it as up arrow key.

But I am not able simulate "v" key. Where can i find the documentation related to this.